# Cant create order with python using binance api

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

when i am trying to create order i got error:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
```

My code:

```
            pos = "SELL"
            q = tbal / price
            q = round(q, 2)
            client.futures_change_leverage(symbol=symbol, leverage=info.laverage)
            print(price * info.stopshort)
            stop = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="SELL", type="STOP_MARKET", stopPrice=price * info.stopshort, closePosition="true")
            take = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="SELL", type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", stopPrice=price * info.takeshort, closePosition="true")
            buyorder = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side=pos, type="LIMIT", quantity=q, price=price, timeInForce="GTC")
```

I tried to solve it by rounding stopprice, but in this way i got error:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error 1111 is simply because the price you have used is above the maximum number of decimal places allowed. For example, if tickSize returns 0.01, max allowed decimal places for that symbol will be 2.

As for error 2021 you are receiving this error because the price of your stop is such that your order would be immediately executed if you were place the order.

For a stop market order to be successful in the case of a BUY long your stop price needs to be above the current market price and in the case of a SELL short your stop price needs to be below the current market price.

If you are short and want to introduce a STOP LOSS you need to have the `side="BUY"` and not `side="SELL"` since you want to close short short and buy back at the market price you have set.

```
stop = client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="BUY", type="STOP_MARKET", stopPrice=price * info.stopshort, closePosition="true")
```

Comment: I understand from what it is happening, but I do not understand how to solve it. now i will edit the question and add my code

Comment: Please explain how to round it

Comment: does this work? `stopPrice=round(price * info.stopshort, 2)` Also can you give real number or more code because the code you provide isn't enough. b

Comment: no, i got 'binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.'

Comment: yes because the stop price is below the current price so it wouldnt be a stop order it would just be a market order and that's why it's being rejected.

Comment: and what i need to do?

Comment: make sure if you are selling that your stopPrice is below current market price and if you are buying that it is above current market price. Are you sure you fully understand what a stop market order is? https://www.thebalance.com/stop-loss-orders-market-or-limit-1031053

Comment: ok look. I add print to my code. Added printing of price, stoploss and takeprofit for short position. My output is "stop loss 23972.01 take profit 21877.37 price 23273.8" And again error "binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.
" IT IS SHORT POSITION!!!

Comment: ok i see now. It's because you have `side="SELL"` you need to put `side="BUY"` since you are short you want to close your short position with a stop that will BUY at market 23972.01 you understand?